# MLE Normal Variance Changing Means

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I have $n$ draws from a 2d normal distribution with a different mean vector every draw. The variance stays constant at $\tau I_2$. How can I get the MLE estimator for $\tau$? Since the mean is changing, it seems 0 or a very small $\epsilon$ is the best, but this doesn’t make much sense in a normal setup.

Comment: Do you know anything about how the mean fluctuates?

Comment: @Ian no!p, just that each draw has a potentially unique mean.

Comment: Then you have a real problem; consider the degenerate scenario where the actual value of $\tau$ is just zero. How can you even statistically prove that that's not the case (so that all the variation is caused by the fluctuation in the mean)?

Comment: I agree with you there, which is why I think 0 may be the best estimate for tau in this setup

Comment: It depends if you have any reason to expect anything about the means at all. If you are truly completely ignorant about it then the "Occam's razor model" is that $\tau=0$.

Comment: what is $I_2$ ? ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi the 2d identity matrix

Comment: @taurus so your covariance matrix is $\tau I $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF of a multivariate normal distribution of dimension $k$ and mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\tau I$ is
$$f_x(x | \mu, \tau) = (2 \pi)^{-k} \tau^{-k/2} \exp(-\frac{1}{2\tau}(x-\mu)^T(x-\mu))$$
Given $N$ observations of the distribution, the likelihood function could be written as
$$L(\mu,\tau) = f_x(x_1,x_2\ldots x_N \vert \mu,\tau) $$
If the observations are independent then we get the following product
$$L(\mu,\tau) = \Pi_{n=1}^N f_x(x_n\vert \mu,\tau) $$
which is
$$L(\mu,\tau) =  (2 \pi)^{-Nk} \tau^{-Nk/2} \exp(-\frac{1}{2\tau}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)^T(x_n-\mu)) $$
The maximum likelihood estimate of $\tau$ maximizes the above or any function that is increasing of the above, one of which is the log-likelihood, which is
$$\ell (\mu,\tau) =  \log L(\mu,\tau) = \log (2 \pi)^{-Nk} \tau^{-Nk/2} \exp(-\frac{1}{2\tau}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)^T(x_n-\mu)) $$
which is also
$$\ell (\mu,\tau)  = \log (2 \pi)^{-Nk} + \log  \tau^{-Nk/2} + \log \exp(-\frac{1}{2\tau}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)^T(x_n-\mu)) $$
Using $\log \exp(x) = x$ we get
$$\ell (\mu,\tau)  = \log (2 \pi)^{-Nk} + \log  \tau^{-Nk/2} -\frac{1}{2\tau}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)^T(x_n-\mu) $$
Using $\log x^a = a \log x$, we get
$$\ell (\mu,\tau)  = -Nk\log (2 \pi) - \frac{Nk}{2} \log  \tau -\frac{1}{2\tau}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)^T(x_n-\mu) $$
Deriving with respect to $\tau$,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\ell (\mu,\tau) = - \frac{Nk}{2\tau} + \frac{1}{2\tau^2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)^T(x_n-\mu) = 0 $$
which gives you
$$\hat{\tau} = \frac{1}{Nk}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)^T(x_n-\mu) \tag{1}$$
But we do not know the mean $\mu$, and hence it should be estimated using the same process, i.e.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\ell (\mu,\tau) = - \frac{1}{2\tau^2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (-2 x_n + 2 \mu ) = 0 $$
which gives us
$$\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N x_n \tag{2} $$
Replacing (2) in (1) we get
$$\hat{\tau} = \frac{1}{Nk}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (x_n-\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{l=1}^N x_l)^T(x_n-\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{l=1}^N x_l)$$